# Laravel-- No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: ajax, laravel, heroku

Desplegue mi app en heroku y algunos iconos no cargan, obtengo este error...

> Access to Font at
>   'http://myapp.herokuapp.com/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2'
>   from origin 'https://myapp.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource. Origin 'https://myapp.herokuapp.com' is therefore
>   not allowed access.

tengo varias funciones con ajax las cuales tampoco funcionan.... todo esto en local funciona correctamente. ¿Que hago?

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Comment: presiento que es problema directamente con heroku y no de la aplicación

Comment: ya he desplegado otras apps en heroku y no había tenido este inconveniente

Comment: cambiale el `http` a `https` o un `//` sin protocolo

Comment: en tu proyecto en la carpeta storage crea una carpeta llamada fonts me paso algo similar, y otra cosa despliegas por consola tu proyecto en heroku?

Answer (score 3):

la url donde llamas tu fuente

> http://myapp.herokuapp.com/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2

Y el dominio de tu app es esta:

> https://myapp.herokuapp.com

Si te das cuenta la url de tu fuente no tiene https eso hace que la url sea distinta a la de origen. La solucion: poner https a tus rutas

Comment: hola amigo, gracias por responder, al cambiar el protocolo de https a http el carga los recursos con el protocolo http.. carga la pagina de forma correcta pero advirtiendo que la conexión no es segura.

estuve leyendo en laracasts.com, y encontre una solucion instalando un package que configura el CORS desde la configuracion de laravel para evitar este inconveniente 

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: @Camilo esta pregunta resurgió porque no marcaste nada como aceptado (pareciera que encontraste tú la respuesta pero no la pusiste para marcarla luego como aceptada)